How to retrieve automatically/periodically the WSS urls that the tab/browser is using and save them to a file?
I'm looking to retrieve the WSS(WebSocket Secure) urls that the Firefox/Chrome browser(only 1 tab open) is using and store them to a file, as often as possible.
Is it possible to do this with minimal resources?
Monitoring packets with custom certificates via Wireshark I think will be too resource hungry.
Maybe a solution from inside the browser would be more efficient?

why not just open your browser's "dev tools" and look at the network tab to see what it's doing?  that way you get to see the contents of exchanged messages as well, most pages I've seen open a persistent web-socket and leave it open as long as possible, so checking for changes shouldn't be needed
